# Unable to install ad-hoc distribution .ipa file using Iphone/ipad

Tags: ios, app-store, udid

I unable to install the my app using the ad-hoc process previouly it used to work and the weird problem im getting is im entering udid's of each device and sending ad-hoc app to that person from past few days whats happening is even though i am adding udid and downloading the provisonal profiles and updating it also the newly added udid are not embeded in it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello @Madpop If you are using Signing in certificates automatically then try it manually and select the newly downloaded provisioning profile in Xcode targets.

[image]

Comment: after adding the new udid in the deveoper account and im downloading the provisonal profiles and updating it and following adhoc process to install the app but after updating also im unable to get the newly added device udids in the .ipa file

Comment: i have updated an image please deselect the "Automatically manage signing" and select the provisioning profile manually in Xcode

Comment: yeah done that even after doing that also same  issue

Comment: are you getting same issue after that ?

Comment: Sometimes it creates problem with Automatically. You should try a new provisioning profile and then add it manually it will work sure for sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159559/discussion-between-sandip-gill-and-madpop).